# Is there any way to check distribution binary for push notifications before uploading to appstore?

Tags: iphone, xcode, push-notification, ios-4.2, apple-push-notifications

My iPhone app is working fine in development phase. Now when I make a binary for the Appstore and upload it, push notifications no longer work. I made some changes and want to upload it again on Appstore, but I want to make sure that push notifications are working fine? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: How are you doing the push notification?  Did you write it yourself or using a third-party like Urban Airship or Notifo?

Comment: yeah i am using urban airship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Verify my making ad-Hoc build...
http://bluxte.net/musings/2009/05/17/ad-hoc-distribution-iphone-application
http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/24/tutorial-list-guideline-for-building-ad-hoc-application-for-iphone/
You need to create different provision profile and also while sending msg from server verify whether you are using sandbox(sandbox.gateway...) or actual...

Comment: i am using xcode 3. i found how to make adhoc build using xcode 4. but i couldn't find how to do that by using xcode 3. can you give me some document or link that how to make adhoc build using xcode 3.

Answer (score 1):

Using Urban Airship they recommend creating two application key. One for development and the other for production.  Are you sure your app is using the proper key? I recommend going over [iOS Push Notification settings](http://urbanairship.com/docs/push_index.html#development-or-production) in Urban Airship documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply compile the app in Ad hoc, and send a notification to the app. In ad hoc, the app use the production certificate.